# AWS CLI query results with list values in top-down format rather comma saperated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

How can we expand a row if a field got multiple values from the query results. Eg . Subnets in the below command go in a long line with comma separated, I would like to get them on the next line by expanding the row.

```
aws ec2 describe-route-tables --query 'RouteTables[*].[[VpcId] | join(`, `, @), Tags[].Value | join(`, `, @), Associations[].SubnetId | join(`, `, to_array(to_string(@)))] ' --output table
```